# Checking if the induced mapping is well-defined

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a nonempty set $T$, $X$ is Hausdorff LCTVS, $X'$ the topological dual of $X$, and $m: \mathcal{M}\to X$  a countably additive vector measure on $\mathcal{M}$.

Let $f: T\to \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{M}$-measurable function. We say that $f$ is $m$-integrable if for each $x'\in X'$, $f$ is integrable with respect to the measure $x'\circ m:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ and for each $E\in \mathcal{M}$ there exists $x_E\in X$ such that for any $x'\in X'$, we have
$$x'(x_E)=\int_Ef\ d(x'\circ m).$$
We shall denote $x_E=\int_Ef\ dm.$

Suppose that $f$ is $m$-integrable. Define
$$n:\mathcal{M}\to X$$ by
$$n(E)=\int_Ef\ dm$$ for each $E\in \mathcal{M}.$ I need to show that the mapping $n$ is well-defined. How do we do this?

Comment: Is $x_E$ in your definition suppose to be unique. If it so, then there is nothing to prove here

Comment: In the book of Kluvanek and Knowles, entitled Vector Measures and Control Systems, at p.21, they did not mentioned the uniqueness of $x_E$. Other authors say that the mapping is well defined because $X$ is Hausdorff, of which I cannot verify why.

Comment: *If* $x_E$ exists *then* it is unique. If $y \neq x_E$ then there is a functional $x'$ separating $x_E$ and $y$ so that $x'(y) \neq x'(x_E) = \int_{E} f\,d(x' \circ m)$. // Integrability of $f$ thus asks for the *existence* of such a point $x_E$ for each $E \in \mathcal{M}$ and it follows that the $E \mapsto n(E)$ is well-defined for integrable $f$.

Comment: @Martin, Why not put your comment as an answer so that I can upvote and accept it.:)I got your idea, as $X'$ separates the points of $X$. Thank you for the smart comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $f \colon T \to \mathbb R$ be $\mathcal{M}$-measurable and assume that $f$ is $x'\circ m$-integrable for all $x' \in X'$. For every $E \in \mathcal M$ there is at most one point $x_E \in X$ such that 
>   $$
> x'(x_E) = \int_{E} f\,d(x'\circ m) \quad\text{for all }x' \in X'. \tag{$*$}
> $$

Suppose $x_E$ has the property $(\ast)$ and $y \neq x_E$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, the Hahn-Banach theorem ensures that there is $x' \in X'$ such that $x'(y) \neq x'(x_E)$. But then
$$
x'(y) \neq x'(x_E) = \int_{E} f\,d(x'\circ m)
$$
shows that $y$ can't have the property $(\ast)$.

The definition of $m$-integrability of $f$ thus implies the existence of a *unique* $x_E$ having the property in $(\ast)$ and the map
$$
\begin{align*}
n \colon \mathcal{M} & \longrightarrow X \cr
 E & \longmapsto x_E 
\end{align*}
$$
is well-defined. The point $x_E$ is *the definition* of the integral $x_E = \int_{E} f\,dm$.